# Mixing codes in a favorite shortcut

Tags: javascript

Can somebody help me with a script?

I mixed that information from various sources in the URL of a favourite:

```js
var lower = 0;
var upper = 20000000;
(function(){
location.href='https://www.deviantart.com/modal/badge/give?badgetype=llama&to_user='+(Math.floor(Math.random()*(upper-lower))+lower)+'&trade_id=0&referrer=http%3A%2F%2FLlamaGivingGame2.deviantart.com%2F';
})();
```

So far it works but...

Is it possible (and how) to add this code in order to the page keep refreshing itself?

```
setTimeout(function() { location.reload(); }, 30000);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `setInterval()`, taking similar parameters with set timeout. Try this

```
setInterval(function() {location.reload(); }, 30000);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!
It didn't work...

The code looks like this now:
 javascript: var lower = 0; var upper = 20000000; (function(){location.href='https://www.deviantart.com/modal/badge/give?badgetype=llama&to_user='+(Math.floor(Math.random()*(upper-lower))+lower)+'&trade_id=0&referrer=http%3A%2F%2FLlamaGivingGame2.deviantart.com%2F';})(); setInterval(function() {location.reload(); }, 3000); 

What am I doing wrong?